# How to use AsyncTask to retrieve RAM consumption in realtime

Tags: java, android, performance, android-fragments

I have a piece of code which I want to run in a loop so that I can get the real time data from that into my fragment.

How can I use `AsyncTask` to get RAM consumption in realtime as i dont want to make my UI Thread busy for this.

```
ActivityManager.MemoryInfo memInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
activityManager.getMemoryInfo(memInfo);
String TotalRam = String.valueOf(memInfo.totalMem);
int totaLram = Integer.parseInt(TotalRam);
String freeRam = String.valueOf(memInfo.availMem);
int freRAm = Integer.parseInt(freeRam);
```

Comment: if i run this into a loop for getting  the data in realtime it will block th UI Thread thats why i thought to use AsyncTask but am new to this and never used it earlier need some guide to make it done

Answer (score 0):

first wrap your RAM codes into a method.

```
 int getRam(){

    ActivityManager.MemoryInfo memInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    activityManager.getMemoryInfo(memInfo);
    String TotalRam = String.valueOf(memInfo.totalMem);
    int totaLram = Integer.parseInt(TotalRam);
    String freeRam = String.valueOf(memInfo.availMem);
    return  Integer.parseInt(freeRam);

}
```

next create an inner-class for your custom asyncTask. you can use a for loop in your doInBackground(), then periodically call the onProgressUpdate() method.

```
public class AsyncRamInfo extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{


 @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        try {
            for (; ; ) { //loop forever
                onProgressUpdate(getRam());
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             return null;    
        } 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

        Integer ram = values[0];
        //display the ram on the UI thread.
        textViewRam.setText(" RAM = "+ ram);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply ... app got crashed after couple of sec.
Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: @andi, two things to take note. 1) this asyncTask should be executed inside the Fragment class, not from another thread and 2) doInBackground() method should not update any views. you can update your question with the new codes for us to better understand the problem.